# DVD playback not working on 13.10

Tags: video, dvd

I could watch DVD's in 13.04 but now that I have upgraded to 13.10 DVDs don't seem to be playable. In Totem video player I get:

```
An error occurred

The movie could not be read.
```

I seem to remember a /dev/dvd device file or /dev/dvdrw... VLC defaults to try to read from that as well, so I don't think I am imagining that. Anyway those are gone and all that remains that visibly pertains to my optical drive is /dev/cdrom.

I have DECSS and the usual stuff installed and playback used to work.

Some further information:

```
mike@sleepycat:~☺  totem --play dvd:///dev/cdrom
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
libdvdnav: DVD Title: Bronson
libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 3b977969
libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): Bronson
libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/mike/.dvdnav/Bronson.map'
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fe0000. Regions: 1

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x0000012f
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x00000177
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x0000017c
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB (0x0000017c)!!
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_0.VOB at 0x001aa417
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x001aa41b
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_0.VOB at 0x001dd024
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_0.VOB (0x001dd024)
libdvdread: Elapsed time 4
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x001ea6f0
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB (0x001ea6f0)!!
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 3 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 4
```

Anyone have some thoughts on debugging this?

Comment: can you check whether [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77750/video-playback-not-working-in-ubuntu-11-10?rq=1) helps you?

Comment: (This problem is also in 16.04.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question, and I have just been working through this too. As far as I know `/dev/dvd` is history, and dvds are now read directly from `/dev/sr0` (as `/dev/dvd` is a symbolic link).

To fix this for 13.10, you can install the "trusty" 14.04 version of the Liborc 0.4 package, [found here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liborc-0.4-0).

1. Download the package from [this site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liborc-0.4-0), making sure to choose the right one (amd64, i386) for your architecture
2. Install the package:

   ```
   dpkg -i package-name-here.deb
   ```
3. Restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

You can enable encrypted DVD playback in Ubuntu 14.04 by using the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

Comment: "command not found" :(